# .NET MAUI unable to launch app on iOS Simulator

Tags: maui, visual-studio-mac

For some reason my app won't launch on iOS simulator. It works on a physical device. The app is deployed but incorrectly and won't run, see **screenshot 1**.

1. If I create a new project, it runs properly. I have compared target platforms and csproj files, both are identical.
2. If I tap the icon I get the message from **screenshot 2**.
3. I don't see any build errors.
4. I use VS for Mac 17.4.2
5. If I run this same app in VS Windows (via parallels) the app starts correctly on iOS simulator.

Any ideas?

**Screenshot 1**
[image]

**Screenshot 2**
[image]

Comment: Did you use XCode14.2? It's not supported by VS for Mac now. You could try using XCode14.1

Comment: Yes I am using Xcode 14.2. Usually I get a message in VS about incompatible Xcode versions. I will give Xcode 14.1 a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 14.2 is still working on and it's not supported yet by Visual Studio for Mac. You could check the release note here [Visual Studio 2022 for Mac v17.4.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/mac-release-notes#1742--visual-studio-2022-for-mac-v1742-newreleasebutton).

As an alternative, you could now try downgrading back to Xcode 14.1 and build the project. If you still have questions, feel free to ask.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I had 14.1 but after a recent update, I had to reinstall .NET workload, and then when compiling, it says I need to use XCode 14.2. After installing 14.2, I could build it but VS doesn't see any simulator. Happened when I had 14.1 as well. EDIT: nevermind, after manually launching it from XCode, it shows up.